# I am doing something wrong with this prototype in JavaScript, any ideas?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype-oriented

The following code doesn't produce a prototype like I thought it might. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
var A = function () {
    return {
        workingTest: function () {return "OK";}
    };
};

A.prototype.notWorkingTest = function () {return "Not so much";};

var a = new A();

a.workingTest(); // "OK"
a.notWorkingTest(); // TypeError: "undefined_method"
```

Any ideas? I thought that this was the right way to extend JS classes, but I am missing something.

Comment: What do you get if you do `console.log(a.prototype)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change A to

```
var A = function () {
  this.workingTest = function () {return "OK";};
};
```

The problem is that your original `A` function was creating and returning a direct instance of `Object` instead of using the instance of `A` that was created by the `new` operator and bound to `this`.

To understand this, try running

```
var B = function () { return { x: 42 }; }
var C = function () { this.x = 42; }
var b = new B;
var c = new C;
alert("b.constructor === B : " + (b.constructor === B));  // false
alert("b.constructor === Object : " + (b.constructor === Object));  // true
alert("c.constructor === C : " + (c.constructor === C));  // true
```

So because `B` returns a new object, the value it returns is no longer an `instanceof B` and does not use `B`'s prototype.

Comment: This fixed it. You, sir, are the hero of the day!

Answer (score 0):

Because `A` returns a separate object, `a` is not an instance of the `A` class; rather, it's an ordinary object which happens to be returned by the `A` function.
It is not connected to `A` or its `prototype` at all.

Instead, you need to assign `workingTest` to `this` inside the constructor and not return anything at all:

```
var A = function () {
    this.workingTest = function () { return "OK"; };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you extend `A`'s prototype while the `new A()` returns an "anonymous" object.

Answer (score 0):

In a modern browser, you can keep your interesting prototyping approach with:

```
var A = {
  workingTest: function () {return "OK";}
};
A.notWorkingTest = function () {return "Yes it does";};

var a = Object.create (A);
a.workingTest(); // "OK"
a.notWorkingTest(); // "Yes it does"

a.extending = function () {return "extended";};
var b = Object.create(a);
b.workingTest(); // "OK"
b.extending();  // "extended"
```

This works according to the ES5 spec.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `A` as a function that returns an object literal.  Using the `new` keyword when calling a function implies that it is a special type of function, namely a constructor.  Constructors in JavaScript must be written in a specific way, setting properties using the `this` keyword.

```
var A = function () {
  this.workingTest = function () {return "OK";};
};
```